# Include files are not being recognized, even though they are in the right directory?

Tags: c++, file, include, portaudio

This is my first post on here, but from what I've seen, you guys like precise and concise problems. I think this qualifies. I have googled hi and lo and might have a case of the dumb, but cannot solve this.

I'm trying to compile a program I found that uses the portaudio library. I downloaded all of them, and HAVE all the relevant files, but visual studio is giving me issues. 
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlc3E.jpg) is the error I get:

So, I decided found the [source path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHBuf.jpg), and tracked down the file, which was in a different folder in portaudio, and copy/pasted it in the appropriate location (can't post third link, but it's there. I can provide that in the comments if necessary, I suppose). . I also have tried putting it in the same directory as the file that actually includes it, adding it to the project as an existing item, and adding that entire directory to the preprocessor include things (project settings > c++ > general > additional include directories).

The second error is very similar and is basically doing the same thing. I have the file, put it in the right place, visual studio can't find it.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: There is the equivalent of an include path. It is it the projects properties page

Answer (score 0):

One possible answer to your problem is that you don't have the right permissions. Are you able to open the file in a text editor?

Comment: I can open the files. They are just normal c++ code. Looks like I have full permissions for them.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out. For the second error, I had to save the .c file to .cpp through visual studio instead of just changing the extension. For the first one, I'm honestly not sure what I did, but it just sort of fixed itself. Such is the magic of programming, I suppose.